# Application to Startup::: Access Error

Tags: vb.net

Hi
I am using following code to add my application to StartUp of Windows.  It works well in XP but gives error in Vista that you donot have permission to edit registty file.

```
Private Sub Forceps_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'Dim regStartUp As RegistryKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run", True)

        'Dim value As String

        'value = regStartUp.GetValue("Myapp")

        'If value <> Application.ExecutablePath.ToString() Then

        'regStartUp.CreateSubKey("Myapp")
        'regStartUp.SetValue("Myapp", Application.ExecutablePath.ToString())

        '        End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by the User Account Control (UAC) feature in Vista. Admininstrators on Vista (and 7 and Server 2008 sometimes) run with a user token that is limited in privileges unless the application explicitly requests them.

Some links to read about UAC and how to configure your application.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc709691(WS.10).aspx

[http://bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2006/10/28/Windows-Vista-*2D00*-Demand-UAC-elevation-for-an-application-by-adding-a-manifest-using-mt.exe.aspx](http://bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2006/10/28/Windows-Vista-_2D00_-Demand-UAC-elevation-for-an-application-by-adding-a-manifest-using-mt.exe.aspx)